# How to display a line of numbers equally in java

Tags: java

Im having trouble only displaying the correct numbers, I know how to get the formula is have count-1 have 10/2 = 5 but now I want to count up from the start making it 10 15 20.

```
//Static void dispalySpace(double start, double end, int count){
// Display numbers between start and end inclusively
//The numbers are spaced equally
//Assume start < end and count is at least 2.
//displaySpace(10,20,3)
//The answer to the question is 10.0 15.0 20.0
while(min<max && count>=2)
       for(int i=min; i<=max; i++) {
          for(double j = count-1; j>=2; j++) {
             System.out.print(j + " ");
                }
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I keep just getting 10-20 displaying on a loop.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. That can't possibly be all your code. Either way, unless you modify the values of min, max and/or count somewhere else, you have an infinite loop there. Start with fixing that.

Comment: To display numbers evenly in a line, use System.out.println(). Check the docs for the width description.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to calculate the steep size, ie what do you have to add to `min` so that you end up with `count`  numbers. For the first output, you won't have to add anything, so it's one less than `count` ,  ie

```
double step = (max-min) / count - 1;
```

That's what you have to add each step of the loop, starting with `min` ,  so

```
for (double i = 0; i <= max ; i = i + step) {
    System.out.print(i) ;
}
```